# Salesforce REST API not allowing to create records by using a reference field

Tags: rest-api, custom-object, relationships, patch

I have 2 custom objects: custObj1 & custObj2. It is a one:Many relationship between the 2. I have set up a lookup relationship under custObj2. Wallet_Address__c is on both objects and is the external id on custObj1

I am trying to get the Wallet_Address__c from custObj1 in my PATCH call to insert a new record in to custObj2 with the same value.

```
PATCH https://mydomain.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v53.0/sobjects/custObj2/Unique_Address__c/custObj2ExternalId

{
    "Amount__c":"2",
    "Contract_Address__c":"someValue",
    "custObj1__r":{"Wallet_Address__c":"someExternalId"}
}
```

but I am receiving the below response.

```
[
    {
        "message": "No such column 'custObj1__r' on sobject of type custObj2",
        "errorCode": "INVALID_FIELD"
    }
]
```

I have tried changing the relationship to master-detail and back. Nothing seems to be working. I suspect in need the actual relationship name to reference in the call but not sure. Any ideas?

**UPDATE** - I am trying to implement **Upserting Records and Associating with an External ID** which is found [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_upsert.htm?search_text=patch).

Comment: Maybe [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/363331/2984) might help?

Comment: I appreciate the help, but I am trying to implement **Upserting Records and Associating with an External ID** found [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_upsert.htm?search_text=patch). It is the exact usecase I am going for. I will try the solution in the link you provided. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! In the text of your question you say "PATCH" but in the code you shared you have `POST`. For upsert you ovbviously want PATCH. I know you may have tried different things and/or copied & pasted the wrong thing - I just want to ensure that you have tried `PATCH`.

Comment: Thanks for the catch @Moonpie. I meant to put PATCH. Good eye! I did resolve my issue and put my answer in the comment.

Answer (score 3):

I have figured out my issue.

I was trying to reference the object name in the __r instead of the actual name of the relationship I created within custObj2. When using the name of the relationship and changing it from __c to __r, it worked.

```
{
    "Amount__c":"2",
    "Contract_Address__c":"someValue",
    "Wallet_Address__r":{"Wallet_Address__c":"someExternalId"}
}
```

In the above, `Wallet_Address__r` is actually `Wallet_Address__c` in custObj2